# Частичное применение Javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть такая задача(вот [тут](https://gist.github.com/codedokode/ce30e7a036f18f416ae0)):

> Напиши функцию partial(fn, a1, a2, ....), которая позволяет 
>       зафиксировать один или несколько аргументов функции. Пример:

```
function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
function mult(a, b, c, d) { return a * b * c * d; }

var add5 = partial(add, 5); // Мы получили функцию с 1 аргументом, которая прибавляет к любому числу 5

console.log(add5(2)); // 7
console.log(add5(10)); // 15
console.log(add5(8)); // 13

var mult23 = partial(mult, 2, 3); // мы зафиксировали первые 2 аргумента mult() как 2 и 3

console.log(mult23(4, 5)); // 2*3*4*5 = 120
console.log(mult23(1, 1)); // 2*3*1*1 = 6
```

подскажите, как это делается. как вернуть функцию с уже вписанными аргументами?

Comment: В "новых" версиях js, лол. Подглядеть полифилл Вы можете в mdn например: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое, что должна делать функция `partial` - это возвращать функцию.

```
function partial(fn, ...partialArgs){
    return function(...args){
        ...
    }
}
```

внутри этой функции должна вызываться функция `fn`, которой должны передаваться аргументы `partialArgs`, а также аргументы args, которые передадут непосредственно при вызове.

Для вызова функции с неизвестным заранее количеством параметров нужно использовать [метод apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
fn.apply(this,partialArgs.concat(args));
```

Так как [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) принимает только одну коллекцию параметров, объединим массивы аргументов с помощью [метода concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Пример:

```js
function partial(fn, ...partialArgs) {
  return function(...args) {
    return fn.apply(this, partialArgs.concat(args));
  }
}

function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function mult(a, b, c, d) {
  return a * b * c * d;
}

var add5 = partial(add, 5); // Мы получили функцию с 1 аргументом, 

console.log(add5(2)); // 7
console.log(add5(10)); // 15
console.log(add5(8)); // 13

var mult23 = partial(mult, 2, 3); // мы зафиксировали первые 2 аргумента mult() как 2 и 3

console.log(mult23(4, 5)); // 2*3*4*5 = 120
console.log(mult23(1, 1)); // 2*3*1*1 = 6
```